# Как убить вывод всплывающих под курсором описание атрибута title

Tags: html, javascript

Вот собственно вопрос. Подходят все варианты, желательно кроссбраузерные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Убрать title.

2) onmouseover="return false;" - не уверен насчет кроссбраузерности. ФФ, например, не хавает.

3) Для истинных извращенцев:

```
var tmpTitle;
```

//...

```
onmouseover="tmpTitle = this.title; this.title=''"  
onmouseout="this.title = tmpTitle;"
```

4) положить сверху прозрачный див. Тоже костыль.

Comment: Предпочтительнее всего - вариант 1 :)<br>
PS:метод 2 тоже извращение, еще то...

Comment: Нет, метод 2 - не извращение. Это вполне очевидное решение, учитывая, что хинт - реакция на наведение. Странно, что не все браузеры это понимают.

Comment: это извращение, а если у элемента уже есть обработчик onmouseover?<br>
Писать всегда `return false`? ИМХО бред..
<br>
И раз так рассуждать то 3ий вариант тоже "не извращение"...

Comment: если уже есть обработчик, то писать return false; в конце обработчика. ^___^ Только не говорите, что вы это не поняли. Ибо если человек написал обработчик, он как-то хоть немного разбирается в механизме его работы.  

Третий - извращение потому что, фактически, мы вынуждены убирать вовсе тайтл при наведении. То есть, ставить костыль только потому что обрубание дефолтного обработчика у нас не всегда срабатывает.

Comment: Я все прекрасно понял, просто считаю что это что-то типа гавнокода :)

Comment: Ну, если это что-то типа говнокода, тогда ответ единственный: никак, пока существует фттрибут тайтл.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(i = 0, il = a.length; i < il; ++i){
    if(1 /*проверка на тег, класс и т.п.*/){
        a[i].removeAttribute('title');
    }
}
```

Убивает все тайтлы. =Р